# Acoustic subwavelength reflection

Tags: acoustics, resource-recommendations, reflection, wavelength

Acoustic Microscopy is usually used for inspection of airgaps in material. I am looking for any source (textbook, paper) that discusses the percentage of reflection of an acoustic wave from an airgap as a function of its wavelength.